# Reduce Logging from @ngtools/webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, aot, ngtools

I'd like to reduce the amount of logging being generated when running a production AoT Angular build with @ngtools/webpack. Currently, it's generating a many MB-big log full of "Resolving module" text. Is there any option I am missing for disabling or reducing this logging?

I have tried setting webpack stats: "none" and it did not reduce this logging.

I am using version 7.3.9 of @ngtools/webpack and version 4.33.0 of webpack.

Comment: Whats wrong with `ng build > /dev/null`?

Comment: I would still want to log errors. My example of "none" was probably confusing - I only did that as a heavy test to see if it was respecting the webpack setting.